# Update from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET Core 3.1: Using Terraform 0.12.31 to build out the AWS Resources: AWS IoT Publish now throws SSL Error

Tags: .net-core, aws-iot, aws-sdk-net

I am doing an upgrade from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET Core 3.1.
I have upgraded my projects to use .NET Core 3.1.  I am using the AWS IoT package described below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents" Version="2.4.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="2.1.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json" Version="2.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.ApiGatewayManagementApi" Version="3.7.0.96" />
      <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider" Version="3.7.1.68" />
      <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2" Version="3.7.0.97" />
      <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.IoT" Version="3.7.6.28" />
      <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.7.4.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="6.15.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.15.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.15.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Now, when I use the AWS IoT package to publish a message I log this SSL Error

ERROR: Exception: Type: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException Message: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Jobs.Function.PostJobDiscussion(APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayProxyRequest, ILambdaContext context) in /codebuild/output/src782906800/src/api/Jobs/src/Jobs/PostJobDiscussion.cs:line 98

I am using a Cloudfront distribution and I redirect my app to HTTPS for this Post api call.

I am building out these AWS resources using Terraform 0.12.31
My cloud front distribution uses an s3 bucket configuration for Terraform is described below

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.webapp_s3.bucket_regional_domain_name
    origin_id   = "S3-${var.account_alias}-${var.domain_name}"
    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.portal_cdn_oai.cloudfront_access_identity_path
    }
  }

  enabled             = true
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true
  comment             = ""
  default_root_object = "index.html"

  // setup a custom error to default to the index.html for the spa
  custom_error_response {
    error_caching_min_ttl = 300
    error_code            = "404"
    response_code         = "200"
    response_page_path    = "/index.html"
  }

  aliases = [var.cdn_domain_name]

  .....

  viewer_certificate {
    cloudfront_default_certificate = false
    acm_certificate_arn            = data.aws_acm_certificate.portal_cert.arn
    minimum_protocol_version       = "TLSv1.1_2016"
    ssl_support_method             = "sni-only"
  }
}
```

I have checked that my certificates in AWS are valid meaning they are not expired but the error says

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Somehow the SSL/TLS handshake is not working

After my upgrade to .NET 3.1 any lambda that is using AWS IoT Publish is failing.

In the browser, the response headers
The Response Headers
content-length: 41
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 08 Dec 2021 16:55:04 GMT
via: 1.1 2d64784a9c03401d2f7f505cbef3c986.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-apigw-id: KChz0HFCIAMFeWw=
x-amz-cf-id: YSrTkIkUyMZY3wiT91WcmFDivk_0cmwlEUE0OeQtD3wGUREz4pXf7Q==
x-amz-cf-pop: IAH50-C2
x-amzn-errortype: InternalServerErrorException
x-amzn-requestid: a00f8e86-de54-44d4-8595-b87a50c04a4b
x-cache: Error from cloudfront

The Request Headers
:authority: api.dev2.project-caisson.com
:method: POST
:path: /jobs/c9b8d1d2-b68c-45d1-9fde-27fa8cc358dd/discussion
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
authorization: jwt token
content-length: 129
content-type: application/json
origin: http://localhost:4200
referer: http://localhost:4200/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36

The Signnature algorithm for the certificate is SHA256WITHRSA

The policy on my lambda for IoT is
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"iot:Connect",
"iot:Publish",
"iot:Subscribe",
"iot:Receive",
"iot:GetThingShadow",
"iot:UpdateThingShadow",
"iot:DeleteThingShadow"
],
"Resource": "*"
}
]
}

These certs have not changed since the upgrade.  I have viewed the certs using openssl command and everything looks fine.

The code in C# that triggers the error is

```
 using (var iotDataClient = CreateAmazonIotDataClient())
                    {
                        var mqttBrokerEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MQTTBroker");
                        context.Logger.LogLine($"Created an AmazonIotDataClient: MQTT Env Variable {mqttBrokerEndpoint}");
                        var serviceURL = iotDataClient.Config.ServiceURL;
                        context.Logger.LogLine($"AmazonIotDataClient: ServiceURL {serviceURL}");

                        context.Logger.LogLine($"iotDataClient Config: ProxyHost {iotDataClient.Config.ProxyHost}");
                        context.Logger.LogLine($"iotDataClient Config: ProxyPort {iotDataClient.Config.ProxyPort}");
                        context.Logger.LogLine($"iotDataClient Config: AllowAutoRedirect {iotDataClient.Config.AllowAutoRedirect}");
                        context.Logger.LogLine($"iotDataClient Config: AuthenticationServiceName {iotDataClient.Config.AuthenticationServiceName}");
                        context.Logger.LogLine($"iotDataClient Config: Url {iotDataClient.Config.DetermineServiceURL()}");


                        //iotDataClient.Config.Validate();

                        // There are three levels of QoS: 0 - at most once. 1 - at least once. 2 - exactly once.
                        await iotDataClient.PublishAsync(new PublishRequest
                        {
                            Topic = $"{latestMessageFromMTT.ClientID}/JobDiscussion",
                            Qos = 1,
                            Payload = new MemoryStream(
                                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobDiscussion)))
                        }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                    }
```

With the CreateAmazonIotDataClient()

```
if (_iotDataClient != null) return _iotDataClient;

            var mqttBrokerEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MQTTBroker");
            var clientConfig = new AmazonIotDataConfig { ServiceURL = mqttBrokerEndpoint };
            return new AmazonIotDataClient(clientConfig);
```

And the ServiceURL is  https://.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

How do I test that this broker is good.  Are there any other tools I should be using to try and identify why I am getting SSL errors?

Comment: The ServiceURL is valid.   I just left out the Id before the .iot

Comment: I have gone to AWS Gateway API and tested my auth token and it is valid too.

Comment: **Ok, folks, This has nothing to do with the Terraform:  The takeaway is that when we have the described architecture on AWS using .NET Core 3.1 with AWS SDK 3.7.5 and the AWS IoT nuget package 3.7.1.49  the iotDataClient.PublishAsync does not work.  I ended up rewriting all of my lambdas that publish to my IoT device in nodejs.  Versions: Nodejs 12.0, awssdk 2.1063.0**

Comment: So Same Environment => Same Certificates => Works in node but not in C#:  Here is the issue I opened in the repo  https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1982 And they labeled it a queued Yea